# Dichroic Glass in Blender

Tags: blender

I am trying to use blender to simulate the Lycurgus Cup.  The cup is an example of dichroic (two-color) glass, and appears green when a light source is on the outside of the cup, and appears red when a light source is inside the cup.

Here is an image of when light is outside and it appears green:
[image: Green Lycurgus Cup]
<sub>(source: [britishmuseum.org](https://www.britishmuseum.org/images/k737_m.jpg))</sub>

Here is an image of when light is inside and it appears red:
[image: Red Lycurgus Cup]
<sub>(source: [britishmuseum.org](https://www.britishmuseum.org/images/k741_m.jpg))</sub>

I have created a glass cup in blender.  I have made the glass a red color, and then used the colorbands under the Object->Material/Shading->Ramps tab to add green specular and diffuse color.  However, this makes the glass appear the same mix of red and green whether I put the light source on the inside or outside the cup.  An example can be seen here: [image: blender image]

According to the second post [here](https://www.indigorenderer.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=23&t=5576), someone was able to

> to fake the effect of a dichroic glass in blender rather easily through the use of a magic
> procedural texture

but they provide no clues on how to do this (in blender).

Does anyone know how to achieve this effect in blender?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution that I ended up going with.  Instead of defining a material with the properties that I needed, I used keyframes to change the material color and alpha channel as the light moved inside the cup.  Here is the result:

Outside:
[image: Green Cup]

In the middle:
[image: Middle Cup]

Inside:
[image: Red Cup]